# proxy using curl and perl

Tags: perl, curl, tcp, proxy

I want to check with a Perl script whether our proxy is working or not. I tested our proxy with a curl command and it worked as expected:

```
curl -x 'http://our_proxy:port' -v 'http://www.some_adult_site.com'
```

This gives me following TCP stream output in Wireshark:

```
GET http://www.some_adult_site.com/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: www.some_adult_site.com
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

When I try that with my Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::UserAgent;
use warnings;

# forbidden URL
$forbidden_url = URI->new( 'http://www.some_adult_site.com/' );

# user agent to use a proxy
$user_agent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$user_agent->proxy( 'http', 'http://our_proxy:port/' );

# request
$req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => $forbidden_url );

# response
$res = $user_agent->request( $req );

print $res->content;
```

I receive a **404 not found** page with the following TCP stream

```
GET http://www.some_adult_site.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.some_adult_site.com
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.05
```

Do you have any suggestions why this is not working ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `agent` to `curl/7.35.0`?

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)) can you write this as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proxy or the site might deny some user agents. Try setting the agent to curl (which you know to work) before you make the request:

```
$user_agent->agent('curl/7.35.0');
```